# Просклонять русские ФИО из дательного в именительный падеж python. Лемматизатор

Tags: python, pymorphy2, pytrovich

Нужно просклонять ФИО из  дательного в именительный.
Например, 'Иванову Ивану Ивановичу' -> 'Иванов Иван Иванович'

Как можно осуществить это?
Pytrovich, насколько я понимаю, склоняет из именительного в остальные

Можно ли сделать это, например, в pymorphy2?
Не нашел в документации информации о самостоятельном изменении тегов, насколько понял, он сам определяет форму, я могу задать характеристики формы слова на выходе, но не могу указать ему, что это дательный падеж, или я ошибаюсь?

В общем,  мб кто-то знает решение/функционал для него?

Answer (score 2):

Метод `parse` дает несколько вариантов разбора (например для "Иванову" там будет и дательный мужской род, и винительный женский род), из них нужно выбрать вариант разбора с дательным падежом (или какой вам нужен), потом просклонять в именительный:

```
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

text = 'Иванову Ивану Ивановичу'
result = []

for word in text.split():
    # Фильтруем только разборы с формой дательного падежа и единственным числом,
    # с помощью next берем первый попавшийся
    # (будет исключение StopIteration, если такого варианта разбора нет)
    p = next(filter(lambda x: {'datv', 'sing'} in x.tag, morph.parse(word)))

    # Просклонять в именительный падеж, слово в этой форме добавить в список
    result.append(p.inflect({'nomn'}).word)

    # Также можно брать нормальную форму (для существительных это как раз именительный падеж):
    # result.append(p.normal_form)

print(' '.join(result).title())  # Иванов Иван Иванович
```

Comment: а мое поделие ```' '.join(morph.parse(s)[0].normal_form.capitalize() for s in input_string.split())``` не взлетело (( без ```inflect``` потому что

Comment: @Jack_oS, у меня работает

Comment: это только на Иванове... попробуйте input_string='Сергею Степановичу Савельеву' или 'Романову Роману Романовичу'

Comment: @Jack_oS все равно работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U68CH.png

Comment: P.S. и на Романове тоже

Comment: а какая у вас версия pymorphy2? на моей 0.8 отдает 'Сергей Степан Савельев' и 'Романов Роман Роман' соответственно

Comment: на 0.9.1 работает-таки :) 'Сергей Степанович Савельев' и 'Романов Роман Романович' спасибо!

Comment: Ну да, 0.9.1. Правда на редких фамилиях глючит. И `normal_form` "Юрьевичу" превращает в "Юриевич", если через `inflect` - то "Юрьевич", так что похоже разница все-таки есть.